# I got composer memory lack error on my ubuntu 16

Tags: laravel

In my laravel 5 app I installed spatie/browsershot and after that got
memory lack error on my ubuntu 16, under Digital Ocean

I rebooted OS and attached swap memory but memory lack error anyway:

```
# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1015908      175784      530992       25336      309132      662096
Swap:             0           0           0
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:~# sudo -s
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:~# sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:~# sudo mkswap /swapfile
mkswap: /swapfile: warning: wiping old swap signature.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1024 MiB (1073737728 bytes)
no label, UUID=76e8a9d1-2d9c-4a3b-a7af-cd152d03532c
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:~# sudo swapon /swapfile
swapon: /swapfile: insecure permissions 0644, 0600 suggested.
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:~# sudo swapon -a
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:~# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1015908      176972      528020       25336      310916      660980
Swap:       1048572           0     1048572
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:~# cd /var/www/html/the-box-booking
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/the-box-booking# mc

root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/the-box-booking# composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
Killed
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/the-box-booking# lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
4.4.0-184-generic
x86_64
```

I do not have a lot of packages in my composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "arrilot/laravel-widgets": "^3.13",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "mews/purifier": "^2.1",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.6",
        "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": ">2.2.0",
        "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "^2.0",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.37",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I suppose that I need to increase memory of my ubuntu instance ( Digital Ocean ).
I have a cheapest instance options, as the app has not a lot of data/load.
How many of memory do I need?
How better to increase options of my ubuntu instance ?

**MODIFIED:**
Added in /etc/fstab:

```
/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0
```

I found and modified php.ini

```
# php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/the-box-booking# sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

with options:

```
memory_limit = -1
max_execution_time = 3300
max_input_time = 240
post_max_size = 400M
```

Also lloked into “Memory limit errors” section of https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md and I run

```
composer clear-cache

php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"

root@ubuntu-boxBooking-Dev:/var/www/html/the-box-booking# php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
-1
```

but rebooting the system to apply my changes I stopped services supposedly I do not need :

```
sudo service apache2 stop
service mysql stop
```

and check memory 1 more time :

```
# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1015908       37652      559028        3136      419228      822304
Swap:       1048572           0     1048572
```

and running composer I again get the memory lack error :

```
 composer install
The "kylekatarnls/update-helper" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1.0 || ^2.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("1.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
Killed
...
```

Are there something else I can try ?

**MODIFIED 2:**
My current options :

```
 1 GB Memory / 25 GB Disk / SFO2 - Ubuntu 16.04.4 x64
  ipv6:  Enable now Private IP:  No VPC Network Floating IP:  Enable now
```

How do you think about these new options :
https://prnt.sc/t666yq
Will it be enough ?
Will I overpay?

Also a question if there a way to return back to my original size ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED:

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED 2: